# Details for reading strings in C?

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone explain how does this work? I know that it reads a string(with spaces), but I don't really understand the mechanism behind. Can someone explain
it to me piece by piece?

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string);
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the man page? if you're on a unix system type `man scanf` and read through it.

Comment: In particular, the final `%*c` instructs to read the terminating `newline` as a `char` and discard the result, so as not to leave the `newline` in the input buffer.

Comment: Here is a good reference of regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Comment: Do you mean you want to know what each element the format string (the `"%[^\n]%*c"`) does, or how the function itself is implemented?

Comment: @LingboTang-- this is not a regular expression.

Comment: You can simply treat `%` as a mark of place holder, `[^\n]` means capture a group of characters except the `newline`, then`%*c` means consume the line by chars.

Comment: These are conversion specifiers, and `%*c` means that one `char` should be read, and its assignment is suppressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page:

> All conversions are introduced by the % (percent sign) character

A conversion is how we match certain text strings. For example a `%s` matches a string, and `%d` matches a decimal integer. So looking at your string, we have a `"%[` conversion, which according to the man page:

> [ Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters; ... the set is defined by the characters between the open bracket [ character and a close bracket ] character.

So this conversion is going to define a list of characters which will be matched and read into your string. Important to this is:

> The set excludes those characters if the first character after the open bracket is a circumflex ^.

And if you look at your string `"%[^\n]%*c"` you've got `%[^\n]` which means that you're matching any character until you hit a newline character.

Next, you have a `%*` the star is a conversion which *ignores* what matches after it. From the man page:

> Suppresses assignment.  The conversion that follows occurs as usual, but no pointer is used; the result of the conversion is simply discarded.

So if you look at your last match, you've got a `c`,

> c Matches a sequence of width count characters (default 1);

so the `%*c` means that you're going to match 1 character, and then discard it (the character being matched is the newline - which the `%[^\n]` didn't consume because you matched everything *up to* that newline), it won't be stored in your `string` variable.

Reading the man page is your friend. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should also hint at the potential buffer overflow since the maximum size is not specified.

Comment: And if the first character is a `'\n'`, `"%*c"` does not happen, `'\n'` remains in `stdin` and `string`  is an unknown stated.

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c",string);
```

This says "read everything until a newline character and then read one character". `*` (in `%*c`) is to suppresses the assignment. That's it reads a line and consumes the newline character.

From [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html):

> An optional '*' assignment-suppression character: scanf()  reads
>   input as directed by the conversion specification, but  discards the
>   input. No corresponding pointer argument is  required, and this
>   specification is not included in the count  of successful assignments
>   returned by scanf().

But I'd, for reading lines, use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) instead and consume the trailing newline afterwards.

```
char string[256];
if (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin) == NULL) {
    /* handle failure */
}
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0; /* For removing the newline if present */
```

which is [less error prone](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and better to understand.

If you are using glibc, you can use [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getdelim.3.html) as well.

Comment: Note that the `scanf()` format fails to read empty lines and causes buffer overflow on lines longer that the destination array. The `fgets()` approach is much preferable, but you should test the return value before attempting to strip the `'\n'` as the contents of `string` are indeterminate if `fgets()` fails and returns `NULL`.